# remove duplicated rows based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have got the following data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'a    b   c   d
                        1   12   2   1
                        1   13   2   1
                        1    3   3   1
                        2   12   6   2
                        2   11   2   2
                        2   14   2   2
                        1   12   1   2
                        1   13   2   2
                        2   11   4   3, header = TRUE')
```

I need to remove the rows which have the same observations based on columns `a` and `b`, so that the results would be:

```
                        a    b   c   d
                        1   12   2   1
                        1   13   2   1
                        1    3   3   1
                        2   12   6   2
                        2   11   2   2
                        2   13   2   2
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score -3, accepted):

We can use `duplicated`

```
df[!duplicated(df[1:2]),]
```